# How can I call a private function with private return type by address

Tags: c++, ios, pointers, void

In a dynamic library, there is a private c++ function:

```
static A convertToUTF8(char *s);
```

and A is a private type, however, I can get the address of this function, so I call the function as below in runtime:

```
typedef void* (myfunc*)(char *);
//assign the address of private function convertToUTF8 to my function pointer
myfunc *convertToUTF8 = (myfunc*)0x000000988;
std:string str = "string";
cahr *cstr = str.c_str();
convertToUTF8(cstr);
```

I find that the parameter which the private function convertToUTF8 receives is not the same as I pass because the return type of my function pointer is void* while A of the private function convertToUTF8.
How can I define a c++ function pointer with unknown return type

Comment: `auto f = convert;`

Comment: Returning a class type probably has a specific ABI requirement, unlike returning a `void*`. You are most definitely not following the ABI.

Comment: How can I call a private function with private return type by address ?

Comment: Shortest answer? You shouldn't. It's private for a reason. Longer answer? You can reverse engineer it into semi-intelligible C++. But no one is going to provide you with a cookbook solution. You'll need to read a lot and do the decoding.

Comment: I find that it's actually caused by register storing wrong pointer, if I call the private by assembley code, can I solve the problem?

Comment: Your code will become incredibly brittle, but you could of course do that

Comment: The register is probably storing the address of the return value. Many an ABI demand it. You really shouldn't mess with it if you aren't aware of the repercussions.